# splitting a string into an array with php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

how would i go about splitting the following format string into an array?

```
[13:05:37] [Server thread/INFO]: [0;35;1m[Server[0;35;1m] hi[m
```

the string format is from a mine craft server and i believe the format is

```
[time] [thread info]: ANSICOLOROPEN[stringANSICOLORCLOSE] string EOL
```

how could i split this so the array would be

```
[0]time 
[1]thread info
[3]ansi open
[4]string
[5]ansi close
[6]string 
[7]EOL marker
```

Comment: What is stringANSICOLORCLOSE in your example? Please, show to what fields do the values from your example correspond.

Comment: colour close is [0;35;1m as is ansi open

Comment: Can you give all the necessary values, that must be parsed for your example: it's complicated - has non-matching brackets

Comment: as i understand it [time] is a time with format         xx:xx:xx[threadinfo]: is a string ending with a : where it gets weird is [0;35;1m[server[0;35;1m] hi [m everything between the two occurrences of [0;35;1m is colored text and [m is end of line so [0;35;1m[server[0;35;1m] hi would render as [server] hi with [server] being purple coloured text

Comment: @Jamesp1989 Did you [check this out](http://theperfectbeast.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/minecraft-server-log-web-interface.html) already?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to start by exploding these types of log entries on the spaces and then hard-code in the index values since those tend not to change. For example:

```
$log_line = "[13:05:37] [Server thread/INFO]: [0;35;1m[Server[0;35;1m] hi[m";
$line_parts = explode(" ",$log_line);

$log_data = array(
 'time' => $line_parts[0],
 'thread_info' => $line_parts[1],
 'somethingansirelated' => $line_parts[2]
);
```

It's much easier to further clean-up your various log datas from here in a variety of ways, for example you could use array_map:

```
array_map( function( $a ){
  // trim, format, validate, etc.

}, $log_data );
```

Not sure if this will get mauled as a non-answer or not but it might help, so here you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all items enclosed by brackets using regular expressions, eg:

```
$re = "/\[([^\]]+)\]/"; 
$str = "[13:05:37] [Server thread/INFO]: [0;35;1m[Server[0;35;1m] hi[m]"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Then you can iterate thru the `$matches` variable which is an array of the possible matches of the pattern being used against your string.

[preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)